# Why is scss mixin not returning color?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to use a mixin to generate a simple set of properties, just `color` and `display: flex`. When I use the mixin while looping through my theme colors, it compile just fine, but when I use it on its own, it only returns the `flex` property.

Here is the mixin:

```
@mixin flex-and-color($color) {
    display: flex;
    color: theme-color($color);
    @debug($color);
}
```

Heres where I execute the mixin:

```
.validation-inline {

    // IT DOESN'T WORK HERE
    .validation-fail {
        @include flex-and-color($danger);
    }

    .validation-disabled {
        @include flex-and-color(#6d6d6d);
    }

    // BUT IT DOES WORK HERE
    @each $color,
    $value in $theme-colors {
        .validation-#{$color} {
            @include flex-and-color($color);
        }
    }
}
```

The `@debug($color)` does display in both scenarios, so I'm not sure why this isn't working. Any ideas?

#### Updates

my theme values look like

```
$theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary": $primary,
    "secondary": $secondary,
    "success": $success,
    "info": $info,
    "warning": $warning,
    "danger": $danger,
    "light": $light,
    "dark": $dark,
  ),
  $theme-colors
);
```

The color variables are just hex values

The outputted css looks like this

```css
.validation-inline .validation-fail {
  display: flex;
}
.validation-inline .validation-disabled {
  display: flex;
}
.validation-inline .validation-primary {
  display: flex;
  color: #007FA3;
}
.validation-inline .validation-secondary {
  display: flex;
  color: #6c757d;
}
.validation-inline .validation-success {
  display: flex;
  color: #008638;
}
.validation-inline .validation-info {
  display: flex;
  color: #007FA3;
}
.validation-inline .validation-warning {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFB81C;
}
.validation-inline .validation-danger {
  display: flex;
  color: #DB0020;
}
.validation-inline .validation-light {
  display: flex;
  color: #f8f9fa;
}
.validation-inline .validation-dark {
  display: flex;
  color: #343a40;
}
.validation-inline .validation-default {
  display: flex;
  color: #eeeeee;
}
```

The colors are:

```
$blue: #007bff !default;
$indigo: #6610f2 !default;
$purple: #6f42c1 !default;
$pink: #e83e8c !default;
$red: #dc3545 !default;
$orange: #fd7e14 !default;
$yellow: #ffc107 !default;
$green: #28a745 !default;
$teal: #20c997 !default;
$cyan: #17a2b8 !default;
$gray-100: #f8f9fa !default;
$gray-600: #6c757d !default;
$gray-800: #343a40 !default;

$primary: $blue !default;
$secondary: $gray-600 !default;
$success: $green !default;
$info: $cyan !default;
$warning: $yellow !default;
$danger: $red !default;
$light: $gray-100 !default;
$dark: $gray-800 !default;
$default: #efefef;
```

To get colors, i'm using the bootstrap theme-color function

```
@function theme-color($key: "primary") {
  @return map-get($theme-colors, $key);
}
```

Comment: What does your `$theme-colors` var look like? I tested this on https://www.sassmeister.com/ with random values for `$theme-colors` and `$danger` (since you didn't include that value either). And it compiled in every case.

Comment: $theme-colors: () !default;
$theme-colors: map-merge(
  (
    "primary": $primary,
    "secondary": $secondary,
    "success": $success,
    "info": $info,
    "warning": $warning,
    "danger": $danger,
    "light": $light,
    "dark": $dark,
  ),
  $theme-colors
);

All the color variables are just hex values

Comment: What does your compiled CSS look like?

Comment: Please add that to the question, and not in a comment.

Comment: @disinfor added the stuff in the question. Sorry I was in the middle of adding it to the question when I got a call lol.

Comment: Can you edit the question with the hex values for your `theme_colors`? They can be whatever, but you should make it so we can test without having to alter your code.

Comment: Do you have a `mixin` for `theme-color($color)` as well? Every time I run your code in Sassmeister, it's outputting the the flex and color property for all of it.

Comment: I'm essentially extending the bootstrap scss, so I'm using their theme-color function. Pasted in the question now.

Comment: Thanks! With that update I can now replicate what you are seeing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211297/discussion-between-jacksonopp-and-disinfor).